# Auth0 SDK (auth0-spa-js) React/Redux Implementation

Tags: reactjs, redux, auth0, redux-thunk

I am having trouble figuring out where to store my instance of Auth0 client with React/Redux/ImmutableJS stack and where to put in state management. All examples are using context/Hooks.

I was thinking about using thunk.withArugment but the problem is the createAuth0Client() resolves async. Has anyone any example of an implementation of Auth0 SDK (auth0-spa-js) with React, Redux, Thunk, ImmutableJS? I know I am probably missing something simple.

I have researched hours on this topic and unable to find an answer. I am using the SDK to not store token on client.

I need to be able to fetch the token prior to all api call's to confirm is user is logged/expired.

I have looked into HOC, Redux Custom Context and still having troubled figuring out what the correct implementation is.

`Updated:`

```
export const isUserAuthenticated = (): ThunkAction<Promise<void>, StoreState, void, Action> =>
  async (dispatch: Dispatch, getState: () => StoreState) => {
    const auth0Client = await AuthService.createAuthClient();
    const isAuthenticated = await AuthService.isAuthenticated();
    dispatchActionWithPayload(ActionTypeKeys.IS_AUTHENTICATED, isAuthenticated, dispatch);

    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      dispatchAction(ActionTypeKeys.LOGIN_REQUIRED, dispatch);
    }
  };
```

Comment: There are plenty of ways to go about this, for instance not creating your store until the auth0 token is available, but wouldn't it just be simpler to add the token to your store like any other data?

Comment: @azium to add the token to the store, you need to go through the SDK of auth0. I can create my own logic but why do it when its already done for you. The process would be, SDK passes configurations (clientID, domain, audience) -> gets initialized -> invoke client.getAccessToken. My delima is getting the async client up and running while figuring out where to store the SDK that has methods and properties. I been trying to to store the SDK in redux.

I will give the delay of store a shot! its a great idea!!

Comment: Cool, feel free to post some code once you have something. This doesn't sound like too hard of a problem (i use auth0 as well, and have lots of redux experience)

Comment: @azium I was able to get passed my blocker by exporting a createAuthClient async function that I awaited in my action layer then followed by what method on the sdk I wished to invoke.

Comment: I believe this would create a new client every time the action is dispatched. I want to make a singelton. What are your thoughts of invoking `createAuth0Client().then(render root react app here)`?

Comment: assuming you're not wrapping that call in `store.subscribe`. only everything below the `<Provider />` will get called again on dispatches, looks fine to me

Comment: you can also call render more than once in case you want to show a loading spinner or something while the auth0 client is being created

Comment: @azium that is exactly what I did. I rendered a loading spinner then on success client initialization I fired off the renderApp function. If error, then I created a error page to be loaded. Since the user cannot use the app at all if not authenticated. The only reason why the client would fail to initialize is if Auth0 is down or our configurations were changed. I appreciate all your help!